# item are updating while scrolling up reyclerview android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

i am making an app in which i have to insert data into reyclerview , the recyclerview is working fine but the problem is that  when i scroll it up  adapter reupdate the data , so to solve this issue the code looks fine but still getting this issue ....................................................

*BaseClass*

```
abstract class MultiViewModelBaseAdapter<M : Model, VDB : ViewDataBinding>(private var diffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<M>) : ListAdapter<M ,BaseViewHolder<VDB>>(diffCallback) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder<VDB> {
        val inflator = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = createBinding(viewType, inflator, parent)

        return BaseViewHolder(binding) 
    }

    abstract fun createBinding(viewType: Int, inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup) : VDB

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder<VDB>, position: Int) {
        bind(holder.mBinding, getItem(position), position)
        holder.mBinding.executePendingBindings()
    }

    abstract fun bind(binding: VDB, item: M, position: Int)


    abstract fun onDataChanged(values: Boolean)}
}
```

*Adapter*

```
 class LanguageAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val mViewModel: LanguageListViewModel,
    private val onClickListener: OnItemClickListener<String>
) : MultiViewModelBaseAdapter<LanguageSupportModel, ViewDataBinding>(diffCallback) {
    companion object {
        private val ADS = 1
        private val LANGUAGES = 2

        val diffCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<LanguageSupportModel>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(
                oldItem: LanguageSupportModel,
                newItem: LanguageSupportModel
            ): Boolean = oldItem.dataId == newItem.dataId

            /**
             * Note that in kotlin, == checking on data classes compares all contents, but in Java,
             * typically you'll implement Object#equals, and use it to compare object contents.
             */
            override fun areContentsTheSame(
                oldItem: LanguageSupportModel,
                newItem: LanguageSupportModel
            ): Boolean = oldItem == newItem
        }
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return position
    }

    override fun createBinding(viewType: Int, inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup): ViewDataBinding {
        return DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.language_view, parent, false)
    }

    override fun bind(binding: ViewDataBinding, item: LanguageSupportModel, position: Int) {
        binding as LanguageViewDataBinding
        binding.apply {
            language = item
            //click
        }
    }

    override fun onDataChanged(values: Boolean) {}
}
```

*Fragment*

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val languageAdapter = LanguageAdapter(requireContext(), mViewModel, this ,lifecycleScope)
    languageAdapter.submitList(LanguageArray.arrayValues())
    reyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    adapter = languageAdapter
}
```

Comment: Your problem is unclear. Are you telling that you for instance edit some EditText's in the items of a recyclerView and that upon scrolling and then scrolling back the edits are lost?

Comment: `i have to insert data into reyclerview ` Ok. But you did not tell if indeed you did that. And when. And you also did not tell how you were going to do that... Or how you did it..

Comment: @blackapps the problem is adapter refreshing the data while scrolling

Comment: Your problem is still unclear as you elaborated nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If You will Use Paging concept in Scrolling then it will Solve.

In the JAVA or KOTLIN We can implement.. like..

- import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;

Then extends it into Adapter Class.

```
public void addList(List<ClsList> list) {
    this.mResources = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged(); // also this main line
}
```

Problem Solve.
☻♥ Have Fun..